# Unable to call Actions from class component. Error: This.props.dispatch is not a function, while implementing the reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So basically I want to implement this package into my application.

https://github.com/Wolox/react-native-redux-toast

but when I try to follow their approach, I'm getting stuck on this issue.

I stuck because I want to use this toaster library via redux 
but when i do that I get the error message:  `this.props.dispatch` is not a function.  bla bla dispatch undefined.

Heres my code on which I can call `Toaster` but actions doesnt work:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  Button,
  View
} from 'react-native';


import { List, ListItem, Divider } from 'react-native-elements'
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as actions from '../actions';
// import { prioritiesFetch } from '../actions';

import { ToastActionsCreators } from 'react-native-redux-toast';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class FollowupScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props){
          super(props);
      }


  componentWillMount(){
    console.log('24---  componentWillMount  in FollowupScreen');
     this.props.prioritiesFetch();
  }




        someFunction = () => {
          console.log(' someFunction called');
          // navigation.navigate('Search');
        }


        static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

          const {state, setParams} = navigation;
          return {
            title: 'Follow Up',
            tabBarIcon:  ({ tintColor }) => {
                return <Icon name="phone" size={25} color={tintColor} />;
            }
          };
        };


    displayInfoToast = () => {
        console.log( '  65 -  ToastActionsCreators ' ,  ToastActionsCreators );
        console.log('64-  this.props = ', this.props );
      this.props.dispatch(ToastActionsCreators.displayInfo('Info toast!'));
    };


    displayErrorToast = () => {
      console.log( '  65 -  ToastActionsCreators ' ,  ToastActionsCreators );
      console.log('64-  this.props = ', this.props );

        this.props.dispatch(ToastActionsCreators.displayError('Error toast!'));
      };

      displayWarningToast = () => {
          console.log('64-  this.props = ', this.props );
        this.props.dispatch(ToastActionsCreators.displayWarning('Warning toast!'));
      };



    render() {
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

      return (
        <View  style={{ }}>
          <Button title={'Info Toast!'} onPress={this.displayInfoToast} />
          <Button title={'Warning Toast!'} onPress={this.displayWarningToast} />
          <Button title={'Error Toast!'} onPress={this.displayErrorToast} />

          <ScrollView>
            <List>
              <ListItem
                  onPress={() => navigate('allProperties')}
                  title="All Properties                                   199"
                  leftIcon={{name: 'flight-takeoff'}}
                  color="rgba(0,122,255,1)"
              />

              </ScrollView>

        </View>

      );
    }
    }



export default connect(null) (FollowupScreen);
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from '../reducers';

const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    {},
    compose (
      applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
);


export default store;
```

Reducers :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import auth from './auth_reducer';
import Fruits from './FruityFormReducer';
import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form'

import { toastReducer as toast } from 'react-native-redux-toast';

export default combineReducers({
  Fruits,
  toast,
});
```

If I try to add the actions like below,

```
export default connect(null, {propertiesFetch}) (FollowupScreen);
```

or

```
export default connect(null, actions) (FollowupScreen);
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should first connect your actions with your component, then the methods will be available on `this.props`. Something like this: `export default connect(mapStateToProps, { dispatch })(FollowupScreen);`

Comment: @soutot Kindly elaborate on "connect your actions with your component"                    const mapStateToProps = state => {
  prioritiesFetch:  "how to do here"
  };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { prioritiesFetch })(FollowupScreen);                                                                                                                How to connect actions with component ?

Comment: you should first import all your action methods, then when you export your class component you should use `connect` passing your mapStateToProps (which contains your reducer state) and then all the action methods you want to use in your component (generally all imported actions). This way both reducer state and your action methods will be available in your `this.props`. Hope it helps

Comment: Kindly elaborate on these statements:   and then all the action methods you want to use in your component  (generally all imported actions).   Can you please tell write me the  mapstatetoProps function for me for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You will not get access to dispatch function in your props. It will be undefined if you pass any argument to connect function. There are two ways to do this.

**Way 1**

call

```
connect()(FollowUpScreen) // without any argument to connect function.
```

Now you can use this.props.dispatch() as you are already doing

**Way 2**

Do the following (I prefer this):

create a function called mapDispatchToprops

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    displayError: (msg) => dispatch(ToastActionsCreators.displayError(msg)),
    displayWarning: (msg) => dispatch(ToastActionsCreators.displayWarning(msg)),
});
```

You can add other actions in the similar way.
Now connect your component with the above function as the argument to connect as follows:

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToprops) (FollowupScreen);
```

Now this will add following functions in your component props:

```
displayError(msg) and displayWarning(msg)
```

you can call them as follows:

```
this.props.displayError('Error Message');

this.props.displayWarning('Warning !!!');
```

Comment: if you read the title of the question "  Unable to call Actions from class component."    but where are you hooking up actions in your answer ?

Comment: Hi, I didn't write the whole code. Just modify your code with the code I have written. Everything else in your code is correct only :)

Comment: Your hella funny, If I knew how to modify the code to make the actions work, why would i be on stackoverflow?

Comment: I can help you in personal chat if you want, because I think this answers your question. You can tell me if there is any confusion in the solution.

Comment: In your component file you can remove 'null' from connect(null) function call. It should work as expected.

Comment: But I dont see where you inserted Actions into the component ?   Not just the toaster actions, but other actions in the project.        This:   actions   import * as actions from '../actions';      that we generally include by writing     export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions )(ScreenName);

Comment: That is what I wrote no. In mapDispatchToProps() function you can map your actions to a dispatched action. and then you can use your actions in props. E.g. say you have an action called action1 which you get by import { action1 } from 'actions'. then you can use it in mapDispatchToProps function like the other two I have mentions. action1: (args) => dispatch(action1(args))

Comment: If there is still some doubt then you can check this link on how to use redux with react: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html. It will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave everything as is and just add your functions to the props, remove your functions from component, then remove dispatch call from your functions, because they to return action object and after connect redux wraps this functions with auto-dispatch them after the call (read redux documentation):

```
const displayInfoToast = () => {
    console.log('  65 -  ToastActionsCreators ', ToastActionsCreators);
    console.log('64-  this.props = ', this.props);
    return ToastActionsCreators.displayInfo('Info toast!'); };

export default connect(null, { displayInfoToast }) (FollowupScreen);
```